# Keras Sequential Model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to create a neural network by using Keras' Sequential API.

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512,activation = 'relu',input_dim = train_data.shape[1]))
model.add(Dense(10,activation = 'softmax'))
```

I get the following error on line 2:

```
The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: 
keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f8ad81d0588>
```

Comment: why you doing this `input_dim = train_data[1]`? you should pass shape to this arg. you can do something like this `train_data.shape[1]`. And please add shape of your train_data

Comment: Oh i forgot .shape but it still gives the same error

Comment: I executed your example without problems. Which keras version are you using? Also, how are you importing `Dense`?

Comment: I am importing Dense like this: [from keras.layers import Dense, Activation].
Also i am writing in a Kaggle kernel

Comment: I think there should be some problem with kernel. Try to use another notebook. Because your code is correct. Usually this error comes up with Input layer to Dense layer. But you are not using Input. So it's ok

Answer (score 0):

You need to use keras.layers.Dense() instead of just Dense(). That should solve your problem

Comment: An answer like this would be better suited to be a comment.